# How to get inline-blocks to take up the whole line?

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm building a menu where every dropdown item has the width of its content. To manage that I had to make the items inline-blocks, but that means they all end up on the same line. Is there a way to make them all on their line without using margins, OR is there a way to have blocks have the width of their content?

Thanks

sample menu item HTML:

```
    <div class="menuItemWrap">
        <a href="#" class="menuItemHead">resources</a>
        <div class="menuItemContentWrap">
        <a href="#" class="menuItemContentItem">articles</a>
        <a href="#" class="menuItemContentItem">web reviews</a>
        <a href="#" class="menuItemContentItem">bookstore</a>
        <a href="#" class="menuItemContentItem">powerpoint</a>
        <a href="#" class="menuItemContentItem">schwab forms</a>
        <a href="#" class="menuItemContentItem">blunck forms</a>


        </div>    

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuItemWrap{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.menuItemHead{
    padding:14px 22px;
    margin: 0px;
    border:0px;
    background:#2389DD; 
}

.menuItemContentWrap{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:100px;
    background:#A6CFD1;
}

.menuItemContentItem{
    display:block;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    background: red;
    color:#333;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: have you tried width:100%; ?

Comment: width:100% makes the width of the items as long as the container's.

Comment: working on adding the code right now

Comment: oh silly me it's supposed to be the other way around, I'll go and hide now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float` removes the width and height of an element. In order to make the elements appear on separate line use the [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) property:

```
float: left;
clear: left;
```

Quote from MDN:

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to
>   floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared)
>   below them.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/cbaoh66r/)

Comment: just tried it, and it works well, thanks! I had tried float left, but I didn't know clear left did that.

Comment: Despite being an old answer this is seriously helpful - especially in my case with a `position:absolute` element which is placed to the right of the container (which is a text lines of different length) which should reside just besides the text. Pair this with a `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` and you have inline-blocks taking up the entire line which are also centered.